# PHP Variable not passing to function

Tags: php, function, variables

I have the following setup:

**class.staff.php**

This defines many variables, the one I'm working with right now is $thisuser->getStaffLang();

**class.language.php**

(Only a function, not a class) This file runs a sql query based on the one variable I pass it from header.inc.php as well as it should pull the staff members unique language ID.

The function is:

```
function translate($TRANSLATION){

$sql="SELECT $TRANSLATION FROM ".LANGUAGE_TABLE." WHERE LANGUAGE_ID=".$thisuser->getStaffLang;
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 $translation = mysql_result($query,0);
 print $translation;
 }
```

**header.inc.php**

First file I'm working with using this function

example translation entry is:

```
translate('TEXT_WELCOME_BACK_STAFF');
```

My problem is that when I'm outside the function $thisuser->getStaffLang; is populated but inside the function it is empty.  I really don't want to have to pass the same variable to the function over and over as some files can have upwards of 20 translations in them and that seems like alot of redundant coding.  Can someone tell me how in the heck I can get that variable to be recognized by the function without have to pass it to it every single time when calling the function? Hope this wasn't clear as mud. :\

Note: Both class.language.php (where the function is and doesn't work) and header.inc.php (where the variable alone works) have required class.staff.php. So they both should be able to utilize that code/variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `global $thisuser;` at the beggining of `translate()`

Comment: Sigh, so simple! Thank you!  I've been banging my head against the wall for this the last 2 hours. :P

Comment: hehe, tried that myself but I don't have the rep for it yet :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark `$thisuser` as global. See below:

```
function translate($TRANSLATION)
{
   global $thisuser;     //<----  MUST MARK global

   $sql="SELECT $TRANSLATION FROM ".LANGUAGE_TABLE." WHERE LANGUAGE_ID=".$thisuser->getStaffLang;
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   $translation = mysql_result($query,0);
   print $translation;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$thisuser->getStaffLang` is probably not a global. You should either make it global, by adding `global $thisuser` to the first line of the function,

or better, pass this variable also in the function scope. So something like this:

```
function translate($TRANSLATION, $stafflang){
// function here
}

translate('TEXT_WELCOME_BACK_STAFF',$thisuser->getStaffLang);
```

Comment: Giving Alon the credit as he answered first (though within seconds) and because I don't want to use the "pass the variable" method you described as there alot of entries I need to do this on and i don't want to have all that quasi-redundant code.  Great answer though too as I know (now) that both ways you mentioned would work.  Thanks very much!

Comment: you should not depend on the variable being there outside the function. Maybe somewhere in the future you change the variable name, or make it function or something, and then it suddenly fails to work, and will give you a lot of trouble then. Whithin functions/classes always have everything local

Comment: btw, it's not about being first, it's about the best answer

Comment: Thank you for the advice and I will definitely keep it in mind.  On this particular variable though I know that it will never change, $thisuser is one of the most important variables in the entire structure.  I'll be sure and remember what you've said though. thanks again.

Comment: "btw, it's not about being first, it's about the best answer" granted, but I specifically mentioned I did not want the way that you described in my original question.